# Is there an updated GLMBooklet.pdf for H2O.ai?

Tags: h2o

I'm interested in using h2o's suite of algorithms to perform some analysis on data, specifically with ordinal logistic regression. I was looking through the available GLMBooklet.pdf and on page 21 of the version available it references a loss function that actually doesn't appear; does anyone know where I can get the details of the loss function, or an updated version of GLMBooklet.pdf with the loss function present? Thanks!

I haven't been able to find the loss function anywhere, but maybe I'm not looking in the right places?